# How do you catch enter key as an error in java eclipse?

Tags: java

this is what i'm trying to do:

User enters numbers into the program and program does stuff with it.

but if the user were to just type the "enter" key (or "return" key) eclipse says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

what i need for eclipse to say is "invalid input" and ask for the input again.

This is how i am getting the input:

I am using one buffered reader in one function, and i am calling the function whenever i need to read input from the user. Here are my codes for this function incase you want to refer to it. Also, the program is a coverage optimization program, incase you wanted to know that as well. Thank you so much for your help!

```
public static String Reader() {
  BufferedReader nerd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String rvalue = "0";
  try {
    rvalue = nerd.readLine();
    if(elements_typed == 0) {
      Integer.parseInt(rvalue);
    }
    if(sets_typed == 0) {
      Integer.parseInt(rvalue);
    }
    return rvalue; 
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print("ERROR: Input must be an integer in [1, infinity]!");
    display_menu();
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.print("ERROR: Input must be an integer in [1, infinity]!\n\n");  
    if(elements_typed == 0) {
      System.out.print("Enter number of elements (n):\n");
      rvalue = Reader();
    }
    if(sets_typed == 0) {
      System.out.print("Enter number of sets (n):\n");
      rvalue = Reader();
    }
  }
  return rvalue;
}
```

Comment: Please take out time to format your code properly.

Comment: What is the complete stack trace?  What line number does it say has the exception thrown?

Comment: well pressing enter will feed in a new-line

Comment: Your error says that it occurred in `main`, but you didn't provide us with the code from `main`.

Comment: Could you post your code fully? What is elements_typed? What is sets_typed? How are they set? I suspect that one of them is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure without seeing more of your code, but I would do:

```
while (rvalue.trim().isEmpty())
{
  System.out.println("invalid input");
  rvalue = nerd.readLine();
}
```

after the `rvalue = nerd.readLine();` statement

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I'VE BEEN TRYING TO SOLVE THIS FOR DAYS.

Comment: @user1687666 Could you accept the answer then? It is the little checkmark under the answer score.